# Easiest way to parse JSON response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Is there any easy way to parse below JSOn in c#

```
{"type":"text","totalprice":"0.0045","totalgsm":"1","remaincredit":"44.92293","messages": [
{"status":"1","messageid":"234011120530636881","gsm":"923122699633"}
]}
```

and in case Multiple results.

Comment: use a library like Json.NET

Comment: Here's a way to do it [Parsing nested json objects with json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204663/parsing-nested-json-objects-with-json-net).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c) will probably help you while using Json.NET

Comment: u can refer to this link similar kind of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Convert your JSON to C# using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/);
2. Create a class file and put the above generated code in there;
3. Add the `Newtonsoft.Json` library to your project using the Nuget Package Manager;
4. Convert the JSON received from your service using this code:

   ```
    RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
   ```

(Feel free to rename `RootObject` to something more meaningful to you. The other classes should remain unchanged.)

Answer (score 25):

You can safely use built-in `JavaScriptSerializer` without referencing additional third party libraries:

```
var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
ser.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Comment: This was helpful to me. DeserializeObject returned an object of type Dictionary<string,object>. The objects in the dictionary were strings, object arrays, or more objects of Dictionary<string,object>

Comment: IMO this is the way to go if you are just doing a simple parse or if you don't want to use a third party library at all.

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to get it without using any external API

```
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            string url = "YOUR URL";
            // attempt to download JSON data as a string
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
                JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var result = jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(json_data);
                Dictionary<string, object> obj2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                obj2=(Dictionary<string,object>)(result);

                string val=obj2["KEYNAME"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me ... the easiest way to do that is using JSON.net do a deserialize to a entity that represents the object, for example:

```
public class Message
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string messageid { get; set; }
    public string gsm { get; set; }
}

public class YourRootEntity
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string totalprice { get; set; }
    public string totalgsm { get; set; }
    public string remaincredit { get; set; }
    public List<Message> messages { get; set; }
}
```

And do this:

```
YourRootEntity data JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourRootEntity>(jsonStrong);
```

Comment: This won't work. `Message` property have json object, not an array of object.  `public List<Message> messages { get; set; }` isn't required simple `public Message messages { get; set; }` would work.

Comment: I just create it with json2csharp, to write a sample.