# Microsoft.Graph Unable to deserialize the response

Tags: json, wpf, azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am quite new to programming and especially `Microsoft.Graph`

I am having problems handling the response to:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children

the response looks like this (just much longer):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('xyz%40hotmail.com')/drive/root/children",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "xyz",
                    "id": "cf58e4781082"
                }
            },
            "createdDateTime": "2009-01-08T08:52:07.063Z",
            "cTag": "adDpFREJDR4RTQMTgxMDgyITEyOC42MzYxODM0MTU0Mjc3MDAwMDA",
            "eTag": "aRURCQ0Y1OEU0A4MiExMjguMA",
            "id": "EDBCF58E471082!128",
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "xyz",
                    "id": "edbcf58e48082"
                }
            }, ............. etc...
```

The response that I received is correct, in JSON format (I believe ><), but I cannot figure out how to parse it into an array containing the folders name.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Have considered using the [Microsoft Graph client library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)? It will deserialize the JSON. Your call will look like this:

```
// Return all children files and folders off the drive root.
var driveItems = await graphClient.Me.Drive
                                     .Root
                                     .Children
                                     .Request()
                                     .GetAsync();

foreach (var item in driveItems)
{
    // Get your item information 
}
```

Here's some samples to help you get started:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=csharp

Comment: The client library is heavily relying on both OWIN and Dependency Injection middle-ware. After testing various examples, I will not recommend this strategy unless you are in the planning phase of a creating completely new project.

Comment: The Graph client library is good, but unfortunately there's still some endpoints it doesn't cover and you need to call them directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`JavaScriptSerializer`** to do this. Assuming

```
//json contains the JSON Response
var jsonOutput = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
jsonOutput.DeserializeObject(json);
```

This has been discussed earlier. See this thread: [Easiest way to parse JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043384/easiest-way-to-parse-json-response)

Refer this link for **JavaScriptSerializer**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx