# Parsing JSON file with multiple keys and different values C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is the JSON file that I want to parse

```
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : [{
        "MarketName" : "BTC-888",
        "High" : 0.00000919,
        "Low" : 0.00000820,
        "Volume" : 74339.61396015,
        "Last" : 0.00000820,
        "BaseVolume" : 0.64966963,
        "TimeStamp" : "2014-07-09T07:19:30.15",
        "Bid" : 0.00000820,
        "Ask" : 0.00000831,
        "OpenBuyOrders" : 15,
        "OpenSellOrders" : 15,
        "PrevDay" : 0.00000821,
        "Created" : "2014-03-20T06:00:00",
        "DisplayMarketName" : null
    }, {
        "MarketName" : "BTC-A3C",
        "High" : 0.00000072,
        "Low" : 0.00000001,
        "Volume" : 166340678.42280999,
        "Last" : 0.00000005,
        "BaseVolume" : 17.59720424,
        "TimeStamp" : "2014-07-09T07:21:40.51",
        "Bid" : 0.00000004,
        "Ask" : 0.00000005,
        "OpenBuyOrders" : 18,
        "OpenSellOrders" : 18,
        "PrevDay" : 0.00000002,
        "Created" : "2014-05-30T07:57:49.637",
        "DisplayMarketName" : null
    }
]
```

How can I parse it to get the "Volume" and "LastPrice" of any marketname existed? There are more than 64 markets, so what is the best way to get it? 
Also i want to compare between old volume and new volume ..

Comment: do you have a c# object which represents the Market json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to parse JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043384/easiest-way-to-parse-json-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this class:

```
public class Result
{
    public string MarketName { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double Last { get; set; }
    public double BaseVolume { get; set; }
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double Bid { get; set; }
    public double Ask { get; set; }
    public int OpenBuyOrders { get; set; }
    public int OpenSellOrders { get; set; }
    public double PrevDay { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
    public object DisplayMarketName { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can get the "Volume" and "Last" from the Result list:

```
string YourJsonString = ".....";

var myClass = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyClass>(YourJsonString);

foreach(var result in myClass.Result){
   Console.WriteLine("Volume: " + result.Volume);
   Console.WriteLine("Last: " + result.Last);
}
```

I have not tested this code, but it should work. If not make a comment.

---

Update based on the comment:

If you want to compare one market with the next market, you can use a for loop instead of foreach:

```
for(int i=0; i<myClass.result.Count;i++){
   if(myClass.Result[i].Volume > myClass.result[i+1].Volume)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Volume "+i+": "+myClass.result[i].Volume+" is higher then volume "+(i+1)+": " + myClass.result[i+1].Volume);
   }

   if(myClass.result[i].Last > myClass.result[i+1].Last)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Last "+i+": "+myClass.result[i].Last +" is higher then last "+(i+1)+": " + myClass.result[i+1].Last );
   }

}
```

---

Update2:

Another way to compare is this:

Declare a global field:

```
private List<Result> _oldResult = new List<Result>();
```

After that, do this:

```
 foreach(var result in myClass.Result){
    // do something with the list

    // compare only, if oldResult is not empty
    if(oldResult.Count == 0) continoue;

    foreach(var oldResult in _oldResult ){
      if(result.MarketName.Equals(oldResult.MarketName)){
         if(result.Volume > oldResult.Volume)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Volume: " + result.Volume);
            Console.WriteLine("Volume: " + oldResult .Volume);
         }

         break;
      }
    }
 }

 _oldResult = myClass.Result;
```

Comment: oh thanks , but also if i want to compare the current volume with previous volume i stored in "X" variable for each market , do you have an idea about how to do it  ?

Comment: declare a variable to hold the volume value above the foreach loop and compare on every iteration of the foreach loop, skipping the first iteration with a null check.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want the maximum volume or minimum?

Comment: I'm getting an error :[ Result : cannot reference a type through an expression. try Coin.Result]

Comment: and in [ .Count ] also error [ Coin.Result doesn't contain a definition for count ]

Comment: I don't want to compare the markets , i want to compare the same market volume but after few time ..
Let's  assume a market has volume of 2 , i want to watch if it increases to 3 as example.

Comment: You are right. I've made a mistake: Please use ".result" instead of ".Result". I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer again, but I think that your asked question above is solved. So please mark it as answered.

Comment: Thanks for you help !! :) i got the idea but didn't test the code :)