# convert jsonstring to objects c#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

i want to get the data from my returning api jsonstring.

my result string looks like this

```
 [
{"Id":12,"name":"testname","type":"testtype"}
{"Id":12,"name":"testname","type":"testtype"}
{"Id":12,"name":"testname","type":"testtype"}
 ]
```

how can i extract this data to c# objects

i can only do it ones

```
    var obj = JObject.Parse(result);
    var ID = (int)obj["Id"];
    var Name = (String)obj["name"];
    var type = (String)obj["type"];

 User u = new User(ID,Name,Type);
```

Comment: Your "result string" is not valid Json. At least not a valid object or collection, but rather three objects one after the other. I don't believe Json parsers will be able to handle this kind of response as it is.

Comment: you **result** is an array of json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is not valid JSON, so making it valid JSON is the first step to process it quickly. The easiest thing to do is to make it a JSON array:

```
string jsonArray = "["
                   + string.Join(", ", json.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                   + "]";
```

From then on it is straightforward (see my related answer: [Easiest way to parse JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34043484/993547)):

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(jsonArray);
```

Another option is to split the lines yourself, and parse and add the items to a list manually.

Comment: but how do you loop over the result? so i can put them in my object

Comment: Using a `foreach` over `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Result is an array of JSON.. so loop and parse

```
  list<User> userList = new list<User>();

    for(int i=0 ; i <result.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Parse(result[i]);
        var ID = (int)obj["Id"];
        var Name = (String)obj["name"];
        var type = (String)obj["type"];

        User u = new User(ID,Name,Type); //create User

        userList.add(u);                 //Add to list
    }
```