# How to convert json array field in c# field

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, json, json.net

I have a JSON like this

```
"type" : "info", 
"gameid" : "info", 
"userid" : "info", 
"actions" : 
[ 
  { 
   "actid" : "info", 
   "type" : "info", 
   "amount" : "info", 
   "timestamp" : "info" 
  },                                      
], 
"i_gamedesc" : "{SystemID}:{GameType}", 
"hmac" : "..."
```

And correpsonding c# code to this json like this

```
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="gameid")]
        public int gameId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userid")]
        public int userId { get; set; }
```

The problem is that i do not know how to convert `actions` JSON array filed like above code.Some help?

Comment: Why not try representing actions with a List, Array, or IEnumerable in C#?

Comment: Could be relevant here: [Easiest way to parse JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34043484/993547).

Comment: Share complete JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to create a corresponding class which will represent object in `actions` array

```
public class Action
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "actid")]
   public string ActId { get; set; }

   public string Type { get; set; }

   public string Amount { get; set; }

   public string Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

then you need to create `List<Action>` property inside your *root* class

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="gameid")]
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userid")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "actions")]
    public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }

    ... other properties ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what i was looking for.