# Getting strings between 2 characters C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which looks like

```
{"BTC":{"USD":7358.8},"ETH":{"USD":402.78},"LTC":{"USD":125.37},"DASH":{"USD":335.73},"XMR":{"USD":187.2},"NXT":{"USD":0.1272},"ZEC":{"USD":204.82},"XRP":{"USD":0.5296},"WAVES":{"USD":4},"BCH":{"USD":705.74},"EOS":{"USD":5.89},"XLM":{"USD":0.229},"ADA":{"USD":0.1601},"NEO":{"USD":52.03},"IOT":{"USD":1.07}}
```

What I want to get are the names(e.g : BTC, ETH, etc), and I was thinking of getting the text before " : " and after " " ", and removing whats unnecessary, but I don't really know if it is a good aproach or how to do it. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: This is JSON, just use JSON.NET to deserialize into a an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> What I want to get are the names(e.g : BTC, ETH, etc)

It sounds like you just want the *keys* of the JSON.

With that in mind you dont even need to care what object the JSON is, just that its a Dictionary of *some* object.  We use a little LINQ to select all the keys and viola:

```
//Gives an List<string> that is a collection of all the coin names
List<string> coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(someJson)
                .Select(x => x.Key)
                .ToList();
```

This results in an `List<string>` that contains this data:

```
BTC,
ETH,
LTC,
DASH,
XMR,
NXT,
ZEC,
XRP,
WAVES,
BCH,
EOS,
XLM,
ADA,
NEO,
IOT
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HOGEWZ)

Comment: Yeah, thats what I wanted and thats what I did, kind of. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

The string seems JSON, so why not just parse it as is?

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    public decimal USD { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "{\"BTC\":{\"USD\":7358.8},\"ETH\":{\"USD\":402.78},\"LTC\":{\"USD\":125.37},\"DASH\":{\"USD\":335.73},\"XMR\":{\"USD\":187.2},\"NXT\":{\"USD\":0.1272},\"ZEC\":{\"USD\":204.82},\"XRP\":{\"USD\":0.5296},\"WAVES\":{\"USD\":4},\"BCH\":{\"USD\":705.74},\"EOS\":{\"USD\":5.89},\"XLM\":{\"USD\":0.229},\"ADA\":{\"USD\":0.1601},\"NEO\":{\"USD\":52.03},\"IOT\":{\"USD\":1.07}}";

        var er = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ExchangeRate>>(s);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you expect multiple currencies, you can use:

```
var er = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>>>(s);
```

Related: [Easiest way to parse JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34043484/993547)

Comment: Yeah, it's JSON, but it will contain ~100 entries like that, and i'd have to manually write that s string you have which I think is not very efficient. But thanks a lot !

Comment: @weaverbeaver thats not how it works, where is your JSON coming from?   The bottom line is your JSON is exactly a `Dictionary<string, ExchangeRate>`, so use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method like Patrick said and pass it whatever JSON string.  If your JSON does not look like your example then you need to provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Solved it, thanks a lot and sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to use ticker API of some `crypto-currency` exchange to create probably a desktop notification app. I created one few months back and here is what i did:

1. Converted `JSON` to `C#` class using `json2csharp.com` website. Name it say `JsonClass`
2. Imported `Newtonsoft.Json` package in my `C#` project.
3. Used following code to initialize class

   ```
   JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(JsonString));
   if (reader.Read())
   {
       JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
       jsonClassObject = serializer.Deserialize<jsonClass>(reader);
   }
   ```

Comment: `JsonConvert` is easier to use.

Comment: Thanks! will try that too.