# c# JSON Parcing

Tags: c#, json

Im having trouble in parsin JSON in C#. I want to parse this Json Format.

```
{
"data": 
  [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "‎0000004", 
    }
  ]  
}
```

Here is my code in C#.

```
 public Data data { get; set; } 

 public class Data
 {
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string code { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: and what is your deserialization code?

Comment: try to use Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON shown is an object that has (as `data`) an *array* of elements that *have* an `id` and `code`, so:

```
public class SomeRoot {
   public List<Data> data {get;} = new List<Data>();
}
```

and deserialize a `SomeRoot` and you should be fine:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeRoot>(json);
var obj = root.data[0];
Console.WriteLine(obj.id);
Console.WriteLine(obj.code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an essential part, the outer object. Also, the data is an array:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Data[] data { get; set; } 
}

RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Next time, follow the steps as outlined in [Easiest way to parse JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34043484/993547). It will help you generate the correct class.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
public class Data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What changed...?

Comment: Yes, I think we add answers the same time :))

Comment: That doesn't matter. What does matter that you didn't state what the problem is and just dump some code.