# Unity convert www.text to dictionary in order to access value?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, unity-game-engine

Ok, I have this that does work trying to fetch weather data - this returns the string version of this dictionary:

```
Loaded following XML {"coord":{"lon":-118.24,"lat":34.05},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":290.19,"pressure":1027,"humidity":17,"temp_min":288.15,"temp_max":292.55},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":1.27,"deg":20.0024},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1548269880,"sys":{"type":1,"id":3694,"message":0.0038,"country":"US","sunrise":1548255306,"sunset":1548292515},"id":5368361,"name":"Los Angeles","cod":200}
```

Code:

```
string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=34.05&lon=-118.24&APPID=33710eba6d9c76286241d779ac1a6d9c";

        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        if (www.error == null)
        {

            Debug.Log("Loaded following XML " + www.text);
```

I want to get the description under "weather" but cant figure out how. Select single node does not work:

```
print(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("cities/list/item/weather/description/@value").InnerText);
```

What can I do here?

Comment: JSON is not XML. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620173/880990) to [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to parse JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043384/easiest-way-to-parse-json-response)

Answer (score 3):

What you get there is a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string not an XML

```
{
    "coord":{
        "lon":-118.24,
        "lat":34.05
    },
    "weather":[
        {
            "id":800,
            "main":"Clear",
            "description":"clear sky",
            "icon":"01d"
        }
    ],
    "base":"stations",
    "main":{
        "temp":290.19,
        "pressure":1027,
        "humidity":17,
        "temp_min":288.15,
        "temp_max":292.55
    },
    "visibility":16093,
    "wind":{
        "speed":1.27,
        "deg":20.0024
    },
    "clouds":{
        "all":1
    },
    "dt":1548269880,
    "sys":{
        "type":1,"id":3694,
        "message":0.0038,
        "country":"US",
        "sunrise":1548255306,
        "sunset":1548292515
    },
    "id":5368361,
    "name":"Los Angeles",
    "cod":200
}
```

If you want to access only one or some few values of that JSON you should use the [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) (simply place all required scripts somewhere in your `Assets`) and do something like

```
var N = JSON.Parse(www.text);

var weather = N["weather"];
```

and than since `weather` is an array (`[...]`) access the single values like e.g.

```
var id = weather[0]["id"];
```

Carefull however because this SimpleJson "hides" incorrect indexes and strings by simply returning `null` instead of throwing an exception. This makes debugging a bit harder sometimes (but could also be changed within the code of the JSON class code).

---

There is also e.g. [Unity's `JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) but it requires that you implement the entire class which is represented by the JSON string. If you do not need all values this might be a lot of overhead when dealing with huge JSONs.

If you need them however (assuming simple types here no `enum` etc):

```
[Serializable]
public class JsonData
{
    public Coord coord;
    public Weather[] weather;
    public string base;
    public Main main;
    public int visibility;
    public Wind wind;
    public Clouds clouds;
    public int dt;
    public Sys sys;
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int cod;
}

[Serializable]
public class Coord
{
    public float lon;
    public float lat;
}

[Serializable]
public class Weather
{
    public int id;
    public string main;
    public string description;
    public string icon;
}

[Serializable]
public class Main
{
    public float temp;
    public int pressure;
    public int humidity;
    public float temp_min;
    public float temp_max;
}

[Serializable]
public class Wind 
{
    public float speed;
    public float deg;
}

[Serializable]
public class Clouds
{
    public int all;
}

[Serializable]
public class Sys
{
    public int type;
    public int id;
    public float message;
    public string country;
    public int sunrise;
    public int sunset;
}
```

and than do

```
var wholeData = JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonData>(www.text);
var weather = wholeData.weather;
var id = weather.id;
```

Comment: When using `JsonUtility`, I was pretty sure you only need to implement the fields that you want access to and unmapped JSON is ignored.  Is this not so? (Admittedly, I've only really used `FromJsonOverwrite()`)

Comment: @Immersive I didn't find this in the docs. It only claims the other way round that `If a field of the object is not present in the JSON representation, that field will be left unchanged.` but it doesn't metnion fields that are present in the JSON but not in the object.